# Equivalent of C++ map.lower_bound in Java

Tags: java, c++, dictionary, treemap

My question is very basic, but I couldn't find the solution myself.

I am used to writing algorithms in C++. There I very often use the `std::map` structure, together with all the auxiliary methods it provides.

This method returns iterator to the first element of the map with key >= to the key given as parameter. Example:

```
map<int, string> m;
// m = { 4 => "foo", 6 => "bar", 10 => "abracadabra" }
m.lower_bound(2); // returns iterator pointing to <4, "foo">
m.lower_bound(4); // returns iterator pointing to <4, "foo">
m.lower_bound(5); // returns iterator pointing to <6, "bar">
```

The cool thing is that the C++ map is based on red-black trees and so the query is logarithmic (`O(log n)`).

Now I need to implement a certain algorithm in Java. I need similar functionality as the one I just described. I know I can use `TreeMap` which is implemented in ordered tree. However I don't seem to find equivalent of the method `lower_bound`. Is there such?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that you're looking for [TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html). Take a look at ceilingKey/Entry methods.

Comment: Thanks I should have looked more carefully, but I somehow thought it should be a method declared directly in `TreeMap`.

Comment: I think `ceilingEntry` method is an exact equivalent of `std::lower_bound`, while `lowerEntry` is very similar but still different.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works for you?

```
SortedMap tail = <Sorted Map Object>.tailMap(target);
if (!tail.isEmpty())
{
    upper = tail.firstKey();
}
```

Comment: This seems more resource-consuming and harder to use than the suggestion of @Nikola

Comment: Actually it turned out you were the one to actually help me, because I am developing for android and the above mentioned method ('lowerEntry`) is not available there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a test case that shows behaviour:

```
@Test
public void testPrefixMatch() {

    treeMap.put("1.2.3", "bar");
    treeMap.put("1.2.3.4", "bar");
    treeMap.put("1.2.3.5.6", "bar");


    assertEquals("1.2.3.5.6", treeMap.ceilingKey("1.2.3.4.5.6.7"));
    assertEquals("1.2.3.4", treeMap.floorKey("1.2.3.4.8.6"));
    assertEquals("1.2.3.5.6", treeMap.ceilingKey("1.2.3.4.8.6"));
}
```

Comment: In what sense you mean his suggestion is not working correctly? I think he suggests exactly the same as you did.

Comment: the suggestion is to use ceilingkey. floorKey is the right to use.

Comment: I think you are wrong into the understanding how `lower_bound` works in C++. It actually fetches the first key that is >= of the given key.

Comment: Ah i see. You are right redacted the answer.thanks for pointing

Answer (score 0):

kind of similar:

In C++

```
vector   lower_bound  return the index
```

In Java

```
TreeSet  higher       return the Key
```