# How to get the longest possible key in java to match a given String

Tags: java

I have written a code to check if a string has the key in a give Map and replace the key with the value in the string.
Below is the code

```
            String s ="VamshiKrishnaA";
    Map<String,String> h = new HashMap<String,String>();
    h.put("Vamshi", "89");
    h.put("VamshiKrishnaA","dataDir");
    h.put("VamshiKrishna","dataDira");

    h.put("VamshiK", "krihsn");

    String key="";

    Iterator<String> i =h.keySet().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()){
        key=i.next();
        if(s.contains(key)){
            s=s.replace(key, h.get(key));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

When i run the above code, i got the output as dataDiraA but i need output to be dataDir.

I dont have control over the order of the key and values it is autogenerated.

Need any help in this regard

Comment: longest *prefix*? Or any match?

Comment: what you are looking for is a lower bound or upper bound search. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598710/equivalent-of-c-map-lower-bound-in-java/48280743#48280743

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to track the length of the currently matched key, and only use the one which is the longest:

```
String matchedKey = null;

while (i.hasNext()) {
    key = i.next();
    if (s.contains(key) && (matchedKey == null || matchedKey.length() < key.length())) {
        matchedKey = key;
    }
}
if (matchedKey != null) {
    s = s.replace(matchedKey, h.get(matchedKey));
}
```

Comment: this is what i am trying to do. I was just worried will this effect the performance by any means

Answer (score 0):

You should call `equals()` instead of `contains()`:

```
if(s.equals(key))
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is some way to order your keys, for example, by length, you might have look at TreeMap, where all keys will be ordered using provided comparator.

On the other hand, if there are not much keys and you knows exact ordering you might just use LinkedHashMap. This way keys will be iterated in the order you have put them. Like this:

```
String s = "VamshiKrishnaA";
Map<String, String> h = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
h.put("VamshiKrishnaA", "dataDir");
h.put("VamshiKrishna", "dataDira");
h.put("VamshiK", "krihsn");
h.put("Vamshi", "89");

for (String key : h.keySet()) {
    if (s.contains(key)) {
        s = s.replace(key, h.get(key));
    }
}
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: The most generic way to solve this problem, I guess, is to iterate through all keys and find [edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) for all of them. Then you just use the value of the key that has the lowest distance. You can tune this solution to find only exact matches (do not allow deletions from your key string) or use other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

**`contains() checks for a sub string , where as equals() checks for whole string , and other difference is , contains() takes object of CharSequence class where as equals() takes Object as its parameter !`**

Using equals() method ::

```
            String s = "VamshiKrishnaA";
        Map<String, String> h = new HashMap<String, String>();
        h.put("Vamshi", "89");
        h.put("VamshiKrishnaA", "dataDir");
        h.put("VamshiKrishna", "dataDira");

        h.put("VamshiK", "krihsn");

        String key = "";

        Iterator<String> i = h.keySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            key = i.next();
            if (s.equals(key)) {
                //s = s.replace(key, h.get(key));
                System.out.println(h.get(key));
            }


        }
```